# Qemu cannot recognize file changes immediately

Tags: qemu, mount, bootloader, osdev

I'm completing [Brokenthorn](http://www.brokenthorn.com/Resources/OSDevIndex.html) OS tutorial where I create a virtual floppy in Ubuntu using MSDOSFS command and then I make changes to this virtual floppy, like changing its MBR using DD command and copying and removing files, the problem is when I make some changes and then run it on Qemu, it doesn't detect changes and shows result as if I hadn't made any change to the floppy drive, but after running and exit qemu some times, it then starts showing me correct result. Why doesn't qemu detect changes immediately?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Do you mean I should mount virtual floppy copy files to it and then unmount it and then use it on qemu?

Comment: I create virtual floppy images using msdosfs command, then mount a folder on it using, "mount imagename.img foldername" command then I copy files to folder using simple cp.

Comment: Thank you so much, your solution worked. Now its working very well. THANKS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are finished updating / deleting / copying files you should use the `umount` command to unmount the directory when finished. That will ensure all the file updates are complete. At that point try running it in QEMU. My guess is that you are keeping the file system mounted while running QEMU. That can cause the type of problems you seem to be observing.